# Django form change instance attribute before saving

Tags: python, django, forms

As I say in title:

```
def profile(request, template='/member/profile.html'):

    .....

    member = get_object_or_404(Member, id=id)

    # >>> member.qrcode
    #  <ImageFieldFile: upload/qrcode/2014-11-12/99_1.41578387725e12.jpg>


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=member)

        # >>> member.qrcode
        #  <ImageFieldFile: 20140901192104.png>

        if form.is_valid():
            member = form.save(commit=False)
.....
```

Form instance `member` change immediately after `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=member)`. 
Because I only want to save member when `member.type == 1` and change some field according to the result of comparing some data in `member` and `form.cleaned_data`.

I think it is very bad to change `member`'s attribute before calling `form.save()`.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

> If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

```
member = form.save(commit=False)
if member.type == 1:
    member.save()
```

Comment: It is nothing wrong with this approach - it is documented. Also in some cases you can use `pre_save` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save where `instance == form.save(commit=False)`

Comment: instance member change immediately after `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=member)`, not `member = form.save(commit=False)` .member had changed before `if form.is_valid():`.

Comment: no, it only creates `ProfileForm` object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: But, actually `instance member` change after I created `ProfileForm` object on my machine `win7 py2.7 django 1.6.7`. Could you do a test?

Comment: I don't have `win7`, but currently using the same `py2.7 django 1.6.7` and it doesn't matter, I've done simple test - model of self.object return `some_field`, I've changed this field in form and sent it to updateview, where put prints `print(self.object)`
            `form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=self.object)`
           `print(self.object)` Result of both the same value

Comment: I think, you've override `__init__` method of `ProfileForm`, so debug it, or show here